# Get confused with scalar projections

Tags: vector-spaces

Use scalar projections to ﬁnd the distance from the point (−2,3) to the line 3x−4y +5 = 0. 
so |-2*3+3*-4+5| / sqrt(3^2 + -4^2) 
just want to know if the equation is correct?
anyone plz verify it?

Comment: This is impossible to read. I guess the $x$ in your solution is probably a multiplication symbol? what does +|5 mean? what do you mean by "+-4^2"? negative four squared?

Comment: it does mean negtive four squared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project the vector from a point on the line to the point on the direction vector of the line, and subtract this from the vector from the point on the line to the point. Find the resultant vector's magnitude.

Note that you can subtract the y intercept of the line from the point to convert the line to $3x-4y=0$ under the new coordinates and calculate the distance, since translations don't affect distances.